# Hide and show div onclick svg

Tags: jquery, html, svg

```
<polygon id="triangle" fill="none" stroke="#EB9381" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="66.233,110.916 114.721,83 66.233,55.083  "/>
<g id="rectangle">
    <rect x="90.908" y="64.82" fill="none" stroke="#EB9381" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="5" height="38" />
    <rect x="71.908" y="64.82" fill="none" stroke="#EB9381" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="5" height="38"/>
</g>
```

Here is my jquery. What I am trying to do is hiding the triangle id="triangle" on click, and showing the rectangle instead. I've tried with a hover effect and it does work. But with the click option it doesn't, I don't know why.

```
function hoverplayer()
{
    $('#rectangle').hide();
    $('#cercle_tourne').click(
        function()
        {
            $('#triangle').hide();
        },
        function()
        {
            $('#rectangle').show();
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: `hoverplayer()` when and how are you calling this function?

Comment: Point to note - `polygon` isn't a **self closing tag**, so if self close it it will make `#rectangle` element to render inside it. so close it accordingly using `</polygon>` otherwise whatever you are trying to `hide` or `show` will not work as expected..

Comment: is `$('#cercle_tourne')` typo? or you have element with id `cercle_tourne`?

Comment: I've closed it, thank you for the info! #cercle_tourne is just a path surrounding the others 
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/33/1439473994-capture-d-ecran-2015-08-13-a-15-52-28.png
Here's the image of the svg, the "#cercle_tourne" is the circle around it, the "triangle" is the play button and the rectangle is the other two shapes. On the image you can see what happens when I click on it, the rectangles do show but the triangle doesn't go away! do you want me to post the svg code too?

Comment: and the hoverplayer() is being called just after the code I put up there. It shouldn't be a problem I guess since it does work when I use hover instead of click, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below! But make sure 'cercle_tourne' is a container or button. And on Click of it it will show the Control(triangle) and on the second click it would hide it.

```
$('#cercle_tourne').click(function(){
    if($('#triangle').css('display') == 'none'){
        $('#triangle').show();
    }else{
        $('#triangle').hide();
    }
});
```

Hope the above helps.

Comment: great it's working! I mean the triangle does show accordingly! The problem now is that the rectangle is always showing, when I only want it to be shown when the triangle is hidden! how do I do that?

- edit ! i've just added two lines for the rectangle and it's working perfectly ! thank you guys for helping!! :)

Comment: Add $('#rectangle').hide(); inside the if condition and on else add $('#rectangle').show();  But it will work according to the display of triangle...

Answer (score 1):

You want to toggle which one is viewed with a button? Yea sure

```
$('.yourButton').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//incase you're using an anchor
    if($('#triangle').css('display')=='block'){//check if triangle is showing
        $('#triangle').hide();
        $('rectangle').show();
    }else{
        $('#triangle').show();
        $('#rectangle').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `.css('display')=="block"`?

Comment: you hitted the point, but you should implement it into OPs code

Comment: @GuruprasadRao oh yea ma bad

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

**CSS:**

```
.hide{
  display:none !important;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#cercle_tourne').click(function(){
   if($('#triangle').hasClass('hide'))
   {
      $('#triangle').removeClass('hide');
   }
   else
   {
      $('#triangle').addClass('hide');
   }

});
```

You can add your own conditions depends upon your scenario

Answer (score 0):

$('.yourButton').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//if you're using an anchor tag if not the remove it

```js
$('.yourButton').click(function(event){
    //event.preventDefault();//incase you're using an anchor
    $('#triangle').toggle('display');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="yourButton">Click Me!</button>
<p id="triangle" style="display:none">Here I Am..!</p>
```

```
$('#triangle').toggle('display');
```

});

Comment: Your code seems to be misformated. Try editing it to look nicier, it also will help readability

Comment: The $('#triangle').toggle('display'); function will add display none property to your polygon just use toggle function and it'll change hide to show and show to hide property to your polygon

Comment: The toggle("display") will change the display property in block to  none and none to bloack